# Using bitwise operators to change all bits of the most significant byte to 1

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Let's suppose I have an `unsigned int x = 0x87654321`. How can I use bitwise operators to change the most significant byte (the leftmost 8 bits) of this number to 1?

So, instead of `0x87654321`, I would have `0xFF654321`?

Comment: `x | 0xFF000000`

Comment: @Yunnosch Noted. Thank you. Merely wanted to improve "unsigned `int`" to "`unsigned int`" but system wanted more before accepting. Tried to make minimal other 'tweaks' to meet requirements. Thank you for the tip, though. :-)

Answer (score 3):

As an `unsigned` in C may be 32 bits, 16 bits or other sizes, best to drive code without assuming the width.

The value `UINT_MAX` has all value bits set.

A "byte" in C is `CHAR_BIT` wide - usually 8.

`UINT_MAX ^ (UINT_MAX >> CHAR_BIT)` or `~(UINT_MAX >> CHAR_BIT)` is the desired mask.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define UPPER_BYTE_MASK (UINT_MAX ^ (UINT_MAX >> CHAR_BIT))
// or 
#define UPPER_BYTE_MASK (~(UINT_MAX >> CHAR_BIT))

int main() {
  unsigned value = 0x87654321;
  printf("%X\n", value | UPPER_BYTE_MASK);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#define MSB1(x)  ((x) | (((1ULL << CHAR_BIT) - 1)<< ((sizeof(x) - 1) * CHAR_BIT)))


int main(void)
{
    char x;
    short y;
    int z;
    long q;
    long long l;

    printf("0x%llx\n", (unsigned long long)MSB1(x));
    printf("0x%llx\n", (unsigned long long)MSB1(y));
    printf("0x%llx\n", (unsigned long long)MSB1(z));
    printf("0x%llx\n", (unsigned long long)MSB1(q));
    printf("0x%llx\n", (unsigned long long)MSB1(l));

    l = MSB1(l);

}
```

Comment: Suggest initializing `x, y, ...`.  Casts not needed as `MSB1()` results in a `unsigned long long`.

Comment: Note: Assumes `CHAR_BIT` is 8. (That's why I avoided it in my answer.)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica indeed

Comment: Minor: `1U << CHAR_BIT` is UB on those rare pesky machines where `sizeof(char) == sizeof(unsigned)`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica quite unusualll

Answer (score 1):

If you know the size of the integer, you can simply use something like

```c
x |= 0xFF000000;
```

If not, you'll need to calculate the mask. One way:

```c
x |= UINT_MAX - ( UINT_MAX >> 8 );
```

Comment: What's wrong with `UINT_MAX-(UINT_MAX>>8)`?

Comment: @rici `UINT_MAX-(UINT_MAX>>8)` may be wrong for OP as _bitwise operators_ was requested.  Usually `-` is not considered a bitwise operator.

Comment: @chux: xor would work just as well.